# How to get a shell session with the fewest number of defined variables (consistent with functioning at a all)

Tags: shell, environment-variables

I am aware of

```
/usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --login --norc --noprofile
```

And indeed, If I run the above, and immediately after run `printenv` in the new shell session, I see that very few *exported* variables are defined:

```
% /usr/bin/env -i /bin/bash --login --norc --noprofile
bash-4.4$ printenv | /usr/bin/perl -lpe 's/=.*//'
PWD
SHLVL
_
bash-4.4$
```

But if instead I run `set`, I see a lot of variables:

```
bash-4.4$ set | /usr/bin/perl -lpe 's/=.*//'
BASH
BASHOPTS
BASH_ALIASES
BASH_ARGC
BASH_ARGV
BASH_CMDS
BASH_LINENO
BASH_SOURCE
BASH_VERSINFO
BASH_VERSION
COLUMNS
DIRSTACK
EUID
GROUPS
HISTFILE
HISTFILESIZE
HISTSIZE
HOSTNAME
HOSTTYPE
IFS
LINES
MACHTYPE
MAILCHECK
OPTERR
OPTIND
OSTYPE
PATH
PPID
PS1
PS2
PS4
PWD
SHELL
SHELLOPTS
SHLVL
TERM
UID
_
bash-4.4$
```

For the sake of this question, let me *define* a shell variable as being "indispensable" iff `bash` simply won't run unless this variable is present (as indicated by its showing up in `set`'s output).  For example, `PPID` appears to be indispensable.  (`bash` emits an error if one tries to `unset` it.)

What is the easiest way to reduce the set of defined variables to hold only the indispensable ones?

Comment: Your question is too broad and would be impossible for anyone to completely answer because it depends entirely on what you plan to do with the system. The bare functional minimum is going to determine that and we have no idea of what that is for you or if it's going to change under certain circumstances.

Comment: Do you understand the difference between shell variables and environment variables? If so, why is your question title "how to get the barest possible **environment**" when you're asking for **shell** variables that aren't environment variables to be removed?

Answer (score 0):

Each and every one of the shell variables that `set` outputs when you run
it in a "clean" shell (no environment variables set through inheritance and no shell startup files read) are set by the shell itself.  They are also documented in the `bash(1)` manual (`man bash`).

For example, the `PPID` variable is documented with

> The process ID of the shell's parent.  This variable is readonly.

Some of these, like `PPID`, can not be changed nor unset.  Others, like `SECONDS` can be both unset and changed (this variable stops being "special" if this is done).

Since none of these shell variables are exported by default, they are not inherited by child processes.  Doing any form of "cleaning up" among these variables is therefore not really needed.

Comment: They *are* inherited by child processes, they are not passed as environment variable when those child (or not) processes execute other commands though.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas By "child processes" I don't mean subshells but processes resulting from executing external commands.